# How to load different content for the same language in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I have a requirement where user would like to display different content for different states within the same country.To be clear i have added (en-us) language version to an item which would display single content to "Florida" state, now they would like to display different content(Image,title,etc..) for "texas" state how we can achieve this? thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do this by personalizing your content based on the GEO/IP rules. you can have different content for each state, and based on the visitor's state you fetch the appropriate content.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by personalizing your content, not by adding different content for each item using the same language.

To show different content (Images, Title, etc) for each state, you can use Sitecore personalization rules "Out of the box".

One of the approaches you can use, and it is very easy to implement:

- Define content for each state, maybe in the Global folder.

[image]

- Go to experience editor, and personalize the rendering components.
- Create new Condition - use the existing rule *"Where the City Compares to Specific City"*.
  [image]
- You can get the list of cities that you can use from this URL: http://www.maxmind.com/GeoIPCity-534-Location.csv  Sitecore uses this services.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But here we are working on POC(Proof of concept) for a particular organization where we would not have site to accessed publicly, this is internal! still can we make the city editable? so that we match always?

Comment: You welcome @EShwar. I'm not getting your question 100%, how the site is not accessible publicly and you want to load different content based on the user's states?

Answer (score 0):

As Ahmad answer use the personalization rules engine to add conditions that personalize your content based on, but I believe if you are using a Sitecore 8.1 and up you can use [Sitecore IP Geolocation service](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/ip_geolocation/setting_up_sitecore_ip_geolocation).

[Sitecore IP Geolocation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/ip_geolocation/setting_up_sitecore_ip_geolocation) provides information about the location and owner of an IP address beyond that provided by a reverse DNS lookup. **IP Geolocation information includes the country, state, city, and the registered company name of every visitor.**

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Ahmad's answer.

If you want to use condition like "city is equal to texas" u need to enable Sitecore GeoIP services first. This is a paid service from sitecore which uses Maxmind's GeoIP in the background.

There is one more option, where you can create new languages in sitecore like en-texas and en-florida. Once you created new languages you can use them like normal sitecore languages. So content editors can fill in different content for those languages.

Comment: Dheeraj Palagiri, correct me if i am wrong! i hope we can not add custom language code like "en-texas","en-florida", i tried adding them but sitecore throwing pop up invalid language code..